# Import moment.js to webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, momentjs

I use webpack with my angularjs project. 
In the `index.js` file, I use "import moment from `moment/moment;`" to import `moment.js`. But when I check `moment().format()` in console chrome, there is error "moment is not defined". What is the right way to import `moment.js` to my project? Thanks

Comment: I don't think webpack has anything to do with this. Have you installed moment in your project?

Comment: Of couser, in node_module folder already has moment.

Comment: Does `import * as moment from "moment"` work?

Comment: It isn't not work too. and I use ES6

Comment: The problem is solved, when I use this config: import moment from 'moment';
window.moment = moment; angular..value('moment', moment)